# attach event by click on a div

Tags: jquery

hi
i have this html code :

```
<div id="#div"><a href="">Test</a></div>
```

i want attach click event on #div when click on div and not click in a tag,

---

**EDITED :**
Please view this page : http://jsfiddle.net/upVex/2/

i want change bg color when only click on space of #div

Comment: Why have an anchor tag within the div if you don't want it to be clickable? Use the correct markup to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a little while to figure out why it didn't work, but you can do that quite easily: http://jsfiddle.net/4FPYf/12/

And the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).get(0) == $(this).get(0)) {
      alert('You clicked me');
    } else {
      alert('You clicked my child');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is my code *really* that hard to implement? It took me 30 seconds... http://jsfiddle.net/upVex/3/

Comment: And one using @Cybernate's code. I think this one is cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/upVex/5/

Comment: thank you, i used return false; I thought return false equal to e.stopPropagation(); this : " http://jsfiddle.net/upVex/5/ " helped me

Comment: Right below this answer? Just upvote it if you haven't already, as he deserves credit too.

Comment: Ahem ! sorry, i'm new user and dont have 15 reputation to vote up . :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a click hander for #div and 
also attach a click handler for the anchor element but stop the propagation of the vent to parent/s.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#div a").click(function(){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("#div").click(function(){
        //Your Code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you not mean this?

```
$('#div').click(function() {
 // Do stuff
});
```

or something like this?

```
$('#div').bind('click', function() {
// Do stuff

});
```

or even something like this?

```
$('#div>a').click(function() {
// Do Stuff
});
```

If you want to do something when the anchor is clicked i'd suggest the last one... but make the href = "#"